# Wordpress: trying to get posts by tag

Tags: wordpress, tags

I've written some code which automatically creates some posts and adds a tag to them.  I can see the tags in the 'All posts' admin panel and I can click on the posts 'Tag' link to get just those posts with the tags.

However, in a plugin that I'm writing using $wp_query no matter what parameters I pass in, I just get the complete list of posts back whether they have the tag that I am looking for or not.

Here's my code:

```
// Now retrieve all items matching this brand name . . .
$query=new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page=5', array('tag' => array($brand_name))));

// The Loop
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    echo '<li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

This produces 10 results when I've told it only to return 5.  In reality I should only get 2 posts back as that's the total number with the tag.

Looking around on the web there seems to be a lot of people having the same problem but no solutions.  I must have tried about 10 different ways of specifying the tag but the fact that the number of posts returned is wrong suggests I've either got something completely wrong or there is some kind of bug.  Wordpress version is 3.4.1 if it helps.

Can any Wordpress pro's shed light on this ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this

```
$original_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'tag' => $brand_name);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        echo '<li>';
        the_title();
        echo '</li>';
    endwhile;
endif;

$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $original_query;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: There should be no reason to reset the original $wp_query and do all that dancing around. Just assign it to a new variable instead.

Comment: @SheikhHeera The whole $original_query, reset postdata, etc.

Comment: @ArtemRussakovskii, in that case i can't use `$wp_query` variable but a different one, for example `$new_wp_query=new WP_Query( $args );while ($new_wp_query->have_posts()) : the_post();...`.

Comment: @ArtemRussakovskii, Tried to use the `have_posts()` instead of `$new_wp_query->have_posts()` without `new_wp_query->` but I think it was not necessary, i could have used what you suggested. Thanks, anyway :-)

Comment: Please note that you need $tag->slug rather than $tag->name, if you are basing on the tag object retrieved from the post.

Answer (score 22):

Answer was found here - https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

> Following example displays posts tagged with 'jazz', under 'genre'
>   custom taxonomy, using 'tax_query'

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'genre',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'jazz'
        )
    )
);
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
```

**So for you it will be**

```
$args = array( 
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'post_tag',
                'field'     => 'slug',
                'terms'     => sanitize_title( $brand_name )
            )
        )
    );

$postslist = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Nice your code. I have query post by tag in single.php It's working well

Comment: what does sanitize_title do

Answer (score 0):

In your code, try:

```
$query=new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page=5', 'tag' => $brand_name));
```

instead of:

```
$query=new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page=5', array('tag' => array($brand_name))));
```

For further details, see https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters
(and as mentioned on a recent duplicate post).

**Note:** $brand_name could be an array of strings, or comma separated values, etc., and the above code should work.

Alternatively, try:

```
$myPosts = get_posts(array('tag' => $brand_name));
```

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while. This is how you get 3 random posts with one of the same tag from a post

```
$post = get_post(); // if you don't have $post->ID already
$tag_ids = wp_get_post_tags( $post->ID, array( "fields" => "ids" ) ); // current tags
$args = array(
    "numberposts" => 3,
    "orderby" => "rand",
    "post__not_in" => array( $post->ID ), //exclude current
    "post_type" => "article", // defaults to "post", also note "any" option
    "tax_query" => array(
        array(
            "taxonomy" => "post_tag",
            "field"    => "term_id",
            "terms"    => $tag_ids
        )
    )
);
$posts = get_posts( $args ); // getting posts
```

if it still doesn't work for you may view sql request that generated by `$args` to troubleshoot it further

```
$q = new WP_Query($args);
echo $q->request;
```