# Wordpress not returning the right value from slug?

Tags: php, wordpress

Lets take into consideration the next sample url:

```
?action=edit&taxonomy=some-categories&tag_ID=183&post_type=some
```

When I execute this:

```
$args=array(
        'name' => 'free',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'numberposts' => 1
);
$post = get_posts($args);
```

I get a empty array even tho the name od this slug contains 2 posts.

Also I tried executing this for debugging matters:

```
query_posts( "cat=183&order=ASC" );
```

But Still returns an empty array()

Any Ideas?

Comment: there is no `name`key in the `$srgs` array in `get_posts` according to http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: so how can I get all the post that are inside that tag_ID ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272997/wordpress-trying-to-get-posts-by-tag ?

Comment: use WP_Query class `$query = new WP_Query( 'tag_id=13' );` tags area explained here http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters

Comment: I know that, and it doesnt work