# need some get_terms help for resources portal

Tags: wordpress

Building a resources part of website which will be a collection of links and files, all added under a "resources" post type.

There are 6 main resource taxonomies (ie: Instructions, Manuals, etc) and then some children of those to better organize long lists of content.

The main archive page is just links to each top level tax, that's working fine.

When someone clicks "Instructions", what I'd like to do is first display all posts in the parent tax (Instructions), and then output each child tax under Instructions as a heading, followed by the posts within it.

So sample Instructions page might look like...

**Instructions (name of parent topic)**

- Post One (these are just in parent tax)
- Post Two
- List item

**Instructions Subtopic**

- Post One
- List Two

**Instructions Subtopic 2**

- Post One
- List Two

Any feedback or starting points would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are mixing taxonomies and terms. Your taxonomy is `resource?` and your terms are `Instructions, Manuals etc.`.

Comment: I tend to do that...  Post Type is Resources.  Taxonomy is Resource Topics.  Terms are Instructions, Manuals, etc.  And terms each have child terms...   Instructions > Child 1, Instructions > Child 2, etc.

Comment: `$posts_array = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'fabric_building',
    'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'fabric_building_types',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $cat->term_id,
            )
        )
      )
    );
` to get posts within your taxonomy, I guess once you have that particular taxonomy you can query posts with that taxonomy and with tags and so on. As a reference to get posts by tag - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272997/wordpress-trying-to-get-posts-by-tag